# Passing ArrayList to Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist

I have MainActivity that has two fragment (Tab1 and Tab2). 
I have fetched data from URL through XML parsing 2 times and store in 2 different ArrayList in MainActivity.

These two fragment has list views. Now i have to pass 1 Arraylist to one fragment and pass 2nd ArrayList to second fragment and then show these ArrayList into ListViews of these two fragments.

How i pass 2 Arraylists to these two fragment and how to show them in these 2 fragments.

This is onCreate method of MinActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loadPage();
    // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);

}
```

I have two ArrayList in another function(OnPostExecute) where i received data thorugh XML parsing.

I haven't edit anything in Two fragments. I just create these two fragment with List View up till now

Answer (score 3):

`Fragment`s have a method called `setArguments(Bundle)`. `Bundle` has built-in support for various `ArrayList`. You simply put the `ArrayList` inside the `Bundle` using a key of your choosing.

However, I do suggest that you follow the `newInstance(<parameters>)` pattern whereby your Fragment has a `static` newInstance() method which takes any arguments the `Fragment` requires to function, in this case an `ArrayList` of some sort.

Quoting an example from the [official Fragment documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html):

```
public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int index) {
    DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();

    // Supply index input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("index", index);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}
```

This `Bundle` can be retrieved later (at any time), but is typically done in `onCreate()` or similar. The `"index"` stored above could be retrieved as follows:

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        mIndex = args.getInt("index");
    }
}
```

In the example above the parameter is an `int`, but the same logic can be followed with an `ArrayList`.

Comment: I would note that you can then read these arguments inside the `onCreate()` method of the fragment by calling `getArguments()`. So in this case `int index = getArguments().getLong("index", 0);` where 0 is the default value.

Comment: @McAdams331 Good idea, I've updated the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: I have to pass List from Activity to Fragment so i create object of detail fragment and set argument in Main Activity method where i have that arrayList?? Right?? Thanks !!!

Comment: @user3585510 Did this answer you resolve your problem? If so, could you please mark this as the answer. If not, please let me know why and I'll see if I can help you further.